# Can this question be reopened or moved to a more appropriate site?

Tags: discussion, migration, closed-questions, specific-question

Question link: [Can I use FFMPEG in a commercial product](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14802/can-i-use-ffmpeg-in-a-commercial-product)

I understand it doesn't directly fall into the scope of this site, but considering the number of votes it's got in comparison with other questions on this site and the fact that it's received an answer from an ffmpeg maintainer, I believe the question must either be reopened on this site or moved to another site (like [opensource](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

Migrating it is a decent idea, however the system unfortunately does not allow migrating after a few months, so there is no way for us to actually migrate it at this point.